# What does "blinding light" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across these example sentences on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/blinding-light) :

> They view things differently, having experienced **a blinding light**.
>
> I am delighted to see that **the blinding light** has struck home in this
>   instance.
>
> Staring into the unknown may just be **the most blinding light** of all.

what does "blinding light" mean?

Comment: Have you looked up _blinding_ in the dictionary? (Hint: your examples all use the expression metaphorically.)

Comment: Often it is used as metaphor for a significant realisation, or revelation.

Comment: @Kate Bunting actually what i wanted to know was the metaphorical meaning of "blinding light" because I'm familiar with the literal one .

Comment: @ Weather Vane thank you so much .

Comment: Although long-since assimilated into general culture as a not overtly religious metaphor, this phrase has biblical roots. See [Conversion of Paul the Apostle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_Paul_the_Apostle#Acts_of_the_Apostles).

Comment: @ stevekeiretsu thank you..that gave me a great background for "blinding light"... i really appreciate it

Comment: @ Weather Vane could you please move your comment to the answer section , I'll accept it .

Comment: Moha, it would have been helpful if you had explained that you were aware that it was a metaphor.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu How can an English phrase have its roots in a book written in ancient Greek? The English phrase must have existed when the book was translated.

Comment: @KateBunting you are right , i should have made this clear , I will keep this in mind the next time I ask a question like this one, I sincerely apologize if my reply to you came across as being inconsiderate , and I appreciate you trying to help me find the answer myself , i really do .